# jquery load content into div and magicline

Tags: javascript, jquery

First post here. Hoping you guys can help. It would be much appreciated and I'm sure I'll learn something. Also, if you see any other redundancies ontop of my problems below, feel free to rip me a new one on coding practices. I need to learn as much as I can asap. On to the problems!

I have two separate scripts that I have half-way there, but I can't get them to function perfectly.

Up first is the "magicline" script. This animates a line underneath the nav based on what page you navigate to.

What I cannot figure out:
1) How to eliminate the extra line width caused by adding a margin-left:"" to space out the nav items.

Second, loading page content with jquery. I'd love to be able to load my 4 separate pages by just calling the content from the supporting pages  section. As of right now, there are two problems. One being, regardless of what page you click on, it reloads the same content over and over. Also, even though the URL updates to the proper page, the navigation "current page" color marker doesnt follow.

To make this much easier to understand, I've got a live demo running here:
http://www.youngsaye.net/v2/

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Thumbs up for "if you see any other redundancies ontop of my problems below, feel free to rip me a new one on coding practices. I need to learn as much as I can asap."

Comment: Wish I knew before hand I could only select one answer, feel guilty not being able to select both of the answers below, as they both helped with different parts of my problem. Almost everything is solved now, save for the size of the magicline. I have some ideas on how to fix it. Any suggestions are more than welcome. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking over the page here's what I'm seeing:

1) The magic line script determines the width of the underline based on the element that has the class "current_page_item".

Since this is all javascript.  You'll want to set up your menu anchors/links to contain javascript that will update the current_page_item class to the selected item and remove it from the previous one.  That should also update your highlighting issue, since it seems that's css styled.

A basic script for this would look like this:

```
function updateCurrent(e) {
  $('.current_page_item').removeClass('current_page_item');
  $(e).parent('li').addClass('current_page_item');
}
```

And all your anchors would have an onClick that looks like:

```
<a href="print.html" onclick="updateCurrent(this);">Print</a>
```

2) I'm not fully following on the main point of your second question.  Navigation looks to point to the proper content when I'm going through it.

EDIT for my added comment below:

```
$('#topnav li a').click(function(){
    // Update the current item.
    $('.current_page_item').removeClass('current_page_item');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('current_page_item');

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

});
```

EDIT Part 2:
I see you're still having issues getting the magic line to disregard your width, what you need to do is while the anchor's are clicked, the same math you applied on initial load should be done as well.

Updated magic line js should look like:

```
// DOM Ready
$(function() {

$("#topnav").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");

// get the left margin of current page item
var marg = parseInt($(".current_page_item a").css("marginLeft"));


/* Cache it */
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

$magicLine
    .width($(".current_page_item a").width())
    .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left + marg)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

$("#topnav li").find("a").click(
    $el = $(this);
    // Do the math for each click
    leftPos = $el.position().left + marg;  
    newWidth = $el.parent().width() - marg;

    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
    });
}, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
        width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
    });    
});

/* Kick IE into gear */
$(".current_page_item_two a").mouseenter();
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll give the suggestions a try. As for the second problem. For some reason, when I was testing locally, the same content would load over and over (Interactive test copy would load on all pages, print, gaming, contact) but now that its live it seems to have fixed itself. Will report back!

Comment: In your pageload.js on the line containing: '$('#topnav li a').click(function(){' you'll want to do something similar to the script I've provided above.  Which is to remove the 'current' class from the previous menu item and update the clicked menu items 'li' element to have the 'current' class.

Comment: That works perfectly. I had added what you wrote previously, but something beyond my comprehension prevented it from working. Your update works flawlessly though. If you have time, can you explain why my version wouldnt work? Is it simply the different between using (e)?

Comment: Nevermind, I see where I messed up. I tried writing another function inside the .click(function() instead of just adding the commands into the already existing .click.

Still a bit confused as to why you don't use the (e) once you've added it into the .click function. If this is terribly obvious, my apologies.

Comment: @funkrush.  Have a look at the updated magicline.js above, that addresses the issue of your sizing the line as each link is clicked.

Comment: Good Lord. I have been staring at this for so long I can't believe I missed that, or admittedly, I didn't quite understand the concept, but now that I see how you've applied the 'marg' variable it all makes sense. Really appreciate all the help you guys have put forth. I can only hope that in a few years I'll be able to help someone out like you guys. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, we'll have to do a little extra math on magicline to not include the margin.

```
// get the left margin of current page item
var marg = parseInt($(".current_page_item a").css("marginLeft"));
$magicLine
    .width($(".current_page_item").width() - marg)
    .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left + marg)
```

We're simply subtracting the margin from the width and adding the margin to the left offset so it still lines up. You'll either have to make this reusable (ie, put it in a function and call it when you click on your a elements) or change the code in your click event to do the same thing. (I recommend the first, no real reason to have the same code in two places)

The logic you want to follow is (something) like this:

- Page load: append the magic line item.
- Line up magicline with `.current_page_item`
- Bind `#topnav li a` click

  1. Animate magicline to the clicked `a` element.
  2. Remove any instances of `.current_page_item`.
  3. Add the class `current_page_item` to the clicked `a` element.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the breakdown in the logic as well. I'll give this a try and report back asap. Thanks again.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. Currently, the margin is applied to all the menu links via the #topnav li a {xxxxxx}. If we are finding the margin for current_page_item, wouldnt it just be adding and subracting 0? Hopefully I'm making sense.

Comment: @funkrush I apologize, I thought you were applying `current_page_item` to the anchor instead of the list item. Answer updated.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the help. It's 3/4 of the way there now. I've updated the live demo for you to see. Currently, I've got the right width for the magicline on the initial page, but once I start clicking through to the other pages the same problem remains. Any idea how I can apply this to all the links simultaneously?

Comment: Im pretty sure the problem is coming from loading content into the div. If i view my source on say, the contact page, it still shows interactive.html as the current_page_item.

Comment: @funkrush as if this morning it looks to be working, so I'm assuming you figured it out :)

Comment: Indeed I did, with the help of you guys. Thanks for following up.